# I am trying to create react application using Vite in vs code but I don't know why it is not creating it stopped after these steps

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm, vite

```
PS C:\Desktop\reactproject> npm create vite@latest
√ Project name: ... portfolio
? Select a framework: » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
? Select a framework: » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
? Select a framework: » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
√ Select a framework: » React
√ Select a variant: » JavaScript
```

I was trying to make a portfolio app but was unable